# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE - calling the ASP.net core web API from Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I received  the following error when i try to pass data from angular application asp.net core  web API.

When i hit the submit button below error appeared in the Angular application please refer to the below screenshots

I have already uploaded the full source code of the asp.net core WebAPI and the angular  application. Please check this and let me know how i can fix this issue. I have tried few times but failed.

[Full Source Code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Kgbp6AKeCIaMBHRYOm52RZyzzgHXUspv)

[image: Screenshot of the Angular Application]

[image: Screenshot of the Error]

Comment: Can you narrow down a part of the code that might be responsible for the error? Attaching an archive of your entire application is not the best way to get a good answer here. Please provide a [mcve] of the code that might be responsible for the error as text.

Comment: Your server expects a `PaymentDetail` with the property of **`CVV`**, while your Angular Client sends a payload with a field of **`CCV`**?

Comment: Thanks  itminus what you said was correct. now the app is working correctly